# Can't run WSL (2) on a Windows 10 VM running in VirtualBox on host macos Big Sur

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, wsl2

I just upgraded a new MacBook Pro from Catalina to Big Sur and found VMWare Fusion was no longer working very well (random network problems, and performance problems leading to timeouts), so I installed Virtual Box.

The performance is fine, but I can't use wsl/ubuntu after following the manual installation procedure as documented at https://aka.ms/wsl2-install

```
PS C:\Users\User> wsl --list -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
 * Ubuntu    Stopped         2
PS C:\Users\User> wsl echo hello
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install
```

I restarted `LxssManager` (which was running), and that didn't help.

For the VBox machine settings, I have
`VT-x/AMD-V`,  `Nested Paging`, and `Hyper-V Paravirtualization` enabled

Any suggestions?

This seems like a fairly generic situation.  To recap:
Host: macOS 11.5.1 (Big Sur)
Hypervisor: Virtual Box 6.1.22
VM: Windows 10 VM (version 2106)

And the problem is: WSL is installed with an Ubuntu subsystem, but can't be run.

Comment: Is nested VT-x definitely enabled in your copy of Virtualbox? https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcgjP.png If not then enabling it down in the Windows may not do anything.

Comment: looks like the VM platform feature is not enabled.  Have you run `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`?

Comment: The VirtualBox 6.0 support for Hyper-V is still [experimental](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/hyperv-support.html). If this is the problem, using WSL1 in the VM, which doesn't use Hyper-V, might work better.

Comment: Answer 1: Yes, nested VT-x is definitely enabled.

Answer 2: If you mean the command at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-3---enable-virtual-machine-feature as part of the manual installation procedure as documented at https://aka.ms/wsl2-install, yes, of course.

Answer 3: Looks like the best answer of the three, but unfortunately I need to run WSL 2.